# How to use the .png pictures as the background on ie6?

Tags: css, png, internet-explorer-6

I want to use the .png（png24） pictures as teh background, but if use the _filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=""),but it can't use the background-position, who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have used IE PNG Fix for using PNGs in IE. It is very simple to use and can be added right into your CSS. He has documentation on the site.

Supports IE5.5+

[http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/)/